# Segmentation Fault coming "Insertion in Binary Search tree." #

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am writing a function to insert a node in **BST**,but getting **segmentation fault.**

```
    /*
    Node is defined as 

   typedef struct node
   {
     int data;
     node * left;
     node * right;
  }node;

   */

    node * findPos(node * tree, int value){
       if(tree -> data > value){
             return findPos(tree -> left, value);
        }
       else if (tree -> data < value){
            return findPos(tree -> right, value);
       }

        return tree;
   }

   node * addNode(int value){

       struct node * temp =(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
       temp->data = value;
       temp->left = NULL;
       temp -> right = NULL;
       return temp;
    }
    node * insert(node * root, int value)
    {
       node * ptr = root;

       if(ptr == NULL)
          return addNode(value);

        else if(ptr -> data > value){
            ptr->left = findPos(ptr -> left, value);
}

      else if(ptr -> data < value){
          ptr->right = findPos(ptr -> right, value);
       }  


       return root;
    }
```

i am not able to understand which illegal memory i am trying to access which is giving this error.
Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to learn how to use a debugger, which will let you run the program until the segmentation fault occurs, then inspect variable values, etc. to diagnose where things went wrong.

Comment: Thanks Jim for follow up on this, i got the error is coming as i have not handled the case in findPos() that tree can be NULL.

Comment: But still the logic is incorrect,trying to find ,but didn't get anything yet.

Comment: @SandeepSingh - You are correct that `findPos` does not handle the case of `value` being larger or smaller than all the `data` values. It will just continue following the pointers until it hits the wall.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1. findPos should handle the case in which tree is NULL.
2. insert should not recursively call findPos. Instead it should recursively call insert. Something like this (haven't tested it):

   ```
   node * insert(node * root, int value)
   {
       node * ptr = root;
       if(ptr == NULL)
           return addNode(value);
       else if(ptr -> data > value) {
           return insert(ptr -> left, value);
       } else if(ptr -> data < value) {
           return insert(ptr -> right, value);
       } else 
           return root;
    }
   ```

Comment: NULL part i get it and i mentioned in my comments also.Still the logic has some issue,your code i tested,it's not working.Thanks for the follow up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys!!!
got the program working

```
   /*
    Node is defined as 

  typedef struct node
  {
     int data;
     node * left;
     node * right;
  }node;
```

*/

```
   node * addNode(int value){

    struct node * temp =(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = value;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp -> right = NULL;
    return temp;
  }
  node * insert(node * root, int value)
  {
      node * ptr = root;

     if(ptr == NULL)
       return addNode(value);

     else if(ptr -> data > value){
       ptr->left =  insert(ptr -> left, value);
     }

     else if(ptr -> data < value){
        ptr->right =  insert(ptr -> right, value);
     }  


    return root;
   }
```